# React FindDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, frontend

I'm using Materil-ui `Select` and I get

> Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.

The solutions I see here are to remove `<React.StrictMode>` to hide the warning.

Here's my `props` flow:

```
In data.js:
export const department =()=> ([
  { id: 1, title: 'Development' },
  { id: 2, title: 'Marketing' },
  { id: 3, title: 'Accounting' },
  { id: 4, title: 'HR' },
]);


In NewEmployee.js:
import data from '../components/data';
import SelectField from '../components/FormControls';
const NewEmployee = () => {
    return (
      <Form>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          <SelectField
            value={values.departmentId}
            name="departmentId"
            label="Department"
            onChange={handleInput}
            options={data.department()} />
        </Grid>
      </Form>
    )
}

export default NewEmployee;


    In FormControls.js:
    import { FormControl, Select, InputLabel, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';

    export const SelectField =(props) =>{
        const { name, label, value, onChange, options }= props;

        return (
        <>
            <FormControl variant="outlined">
                <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    label={label}
                    name={name}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={onChange}>
                    <MenuItem value="">...</MenuItem>
                    {options.map((item) => (
                        <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>{item.title}</MenuItem>
                    )
                )}
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
        </>
        );
    };
```

How do I actually solve it without hiding it?

Comment: Are you using `findDomNode` in your code? or is this from material UI?

Comment: from material UI

Comment: Then I dont think there is anything you can do on your end to "solve" it.